# NameError: uninitialized constant Api::V1::Item::ItemsController::Item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, postman

I have controller

```
class Api::V1::Item::ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @items = Item.all 

     render json: @items
  end
end
```

and routes for this controller

```
 namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
   namespace :item do
     resources :items
   end
  end
 end
```

If i check this in postman, i obtain an error:

```
{
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "#<NameError: uninitialized constant Api::V1::Item::ItemsController::Item>",
 }
```

But if i modify controller`s method index like

```
  def index
     render json: { check: 'Nice' }
  end
```

everything will be fine. Pls explain me what the problem is

Comment: Why i cant call model Item in controller???

Comment: call as `::Item` this will force lookup at the top level. Right now your namespacing also defines `Item` as in Api::V1:: **Item** ::ItemsController but that constant does not actually exist it only exists as part of this namespacing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using **absolute** constant path `::Item` instead of **relative** constant path `Item`.

```
def index
  @items = ::Item.all
  # ...
```

Comment: Please expound otherwise this could just be a comment like mine :)

Comment: @engineersmnky Don't see your comment :)

Comment: Alternative: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable.html#method-i-require_dependency

Comment: @ТарасМатіїв  engineersmnky gave a good explanation. I suggest to avoid of using `namespace :item do` in your routing.